# DB restoration issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

I have a issue while trying to restore a DB. Earlier I had SQL Server 2000 on my system so I installed SQL Server 2005 and now I'm trying to upload a DB backup made on SQL Server 2005 only. While uploading that I'm getting the following:

The query is

```
restore database APR15THB from disk ='C:\datab\APR15MUR.bak' with replace ,
move 'Apr07Trans_dat' to 'c:\overseas\mil-data\APR15THB.mdf',
move 'Apr07Trans_log' to 'c:\overseas\mil-data\APR15THB.ldf'
```

The error is

> Msg 3169, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The backed-up database has on-disk structure version 611. The server supports version 539 and cannot restore or upgrade this database.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: No programming question - database administration is handled on dba.stackexchange.com. Oh, and you can not restore a version from a more modern SQL Server on an older version. Simple like that - you need to upgrade. THe backup was OBVIOUSLY not made with SQL Server 2005 - otherwise the disc structure version would not be higher than yours. Service pack? Patching?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not restore a backup taken with a more modern version to a more outdated sql server.

SImple like that.

ALL your server versions are old, but you running 2000 is ancient. What about doing an update like every 15 years?

Check

https://support.software.dell.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/kb/30314

(yeah, google really has a lot on that stuff). Quite obviously you seem still to restore on 2000. Getting confused with multiple instances installed - i.e. you did not upgrade 2000 to 2005 but installed 2005 side by side and still use the 2000 version for restore?

Comment: @tomtom...thanks but I have already installed a sql server 2005 and running the restoration on 2005 only...

Comment: OBVIOUSLY not. Really.

Comment: @tom...yes i have installed it in the same server where SS 2000 were there...still its not working

Comment: @user3305327, the error message means you are trying to restore a SQL 2005 backup to a SQL 2000 instance.  See http://www.dbdelta.com/internal-sql-server-database-version-numbers/ for the version number mapping.  Execute SELECT @@VERSION on you target instance and I expect it will indicate SQL 2000.

Comment: @DanGuzman...thanks for procedure...am really astonished as its showing me sql server 2000...whereas i have installed 2005 and running the query from sql server management studio...

Comment: Well, then you either haven ot installed the 2005 database engine OR you have not upgraded but installed another instance in parallel. As I already told you.